# C# SQL Close Reader

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I am writing a program to add information from a Form into my database, however, when running the program I am met with the following syntax error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.'

If I don't close the reader the statement `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` will not be run as there is already an open DataReader associated with this Command.

Here is the source:

```
        string isbnQuery = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn = '" + txtbox_id.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCmdQuery = new SqlCommand(isbnQuery, sqlCon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(isbnQuery, sqlCon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dtbl);

        if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                using (sqlCon)
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Is this Correct?", reader["title"].ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("book_log", sqlCon);
                            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            // adding text-field data to the database

                            char current = 'N';

                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_id", reader["book_id"]);
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID.getID);
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_from", dtp_from.Value.ToString());
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_to", dtp_hand.Value.ToString());
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fine", current);
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@handed", current);


                            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            MessageBox.Show("Done!");

                        }
                        else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Contact a Staff Member " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Book Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to re-create your command. Open, close and dispose connections and commands. Use parameters to prevent sqli. Also you filled a datatable already, get your `book_id` from that, you dont need a reader at all. TBH all this can be done in one shot to the db.

Comment: You need to add to your connectionstring the key _[MultipleActiveResultSets=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars#:~:text=Multiple%20Active%20Result%20Sets%20%28MARS%29%20is%20a%20feature,MARS%20does%20not%20imply%20simultaneous%20execution%20of%20operations.)_

Comment: Also you can optimize a bit this code creating the _sqlCmd_  variabile and its parameters outside the inner loop. In that loop just update the parameter's values

Comment: Don't try to "nest" SQL instructions. Issue your first `SELECT`, read it fully (instead of using the results directly in the `reader.read()` loop), then loop in the in-memory copy and issue further queries from there.

Comment: you can probably get away with this style if you do it under same transaction. But it is not going to be nice. As @Alejandro pointed out - read data first into some array and then execute stored proc. Alternatively, you can build a block of `Exec` and pass the entire block to execute on the server. But if you have many records, you might want to split into parts or bulk otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it, I listened to some of the comments and have found a solution, this is my first time working with databases so any feedback was welcome.